# C# Lambda para Java Lambda

Tags: java, c#, expressões-lambda

Eu tenho este código em C#. Uma expressão lambda que busca arquivos em um diretório usando regex e joga esses arquivos em uma função executando uma linha de comando.
Todos os arquivos encontrados são adicionados em "Task" para serem executados em paralelo.
Como seria o correspondente desta expressão em Java?

```
_ = await Task.Run(() =>
          {
              return Parallel.ForEach(GameFiles.Where(f => Regex.IsMatch(f, pattern: FileLocationInfo.DlgPattern)), item => tw.GetFile($"-e -t", item));
          });
```

Edit: "GameFiles" contem a pasta com vários arquivos de um jogo.
"Regex" é usado para selecionar apenas os arquivos que quero. Tem arquivos com mesma extensão que não me interessa.
"tw.GetFile" é um método com o app em linha de comando.

"**Regex**" seleciona os arquivos em "**GameFiles**", que são jogados um a um no método "**tw.GetFiles**" e então executados em paralelo.

O app é de alguns KB e os arquivos tem 4MB no máximo. É mais conveniente executar em paralelo.

Comment: não me parece ser uma questão do lambda... mas sim o recurso do `Paralell.ForEach`. Apresente o código de como você está tentando reproduzir esse trecho de código no Java.

Comment: Em relação ao `Paralell.ForEach` consegues através `Stream::parallelStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Em princípio será qualquer do género, assumindo que o `GameFiles` é uma lista de nomes de ficheiros. Tens é de ver a condição do `Where` que em Java é `filter` e o respectivo mapeamento através do `map`. No final coloquei tudo numa lista com a chamada ao `collect(Collectors.toList())`.

```java
gameFiles.parallelStream()
    .filter(f => ...)
    .map(item => ...)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Para mais sobre Streams paralelas no Java vê [isto](https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-parallel-streams-examples/).